# Could not download upgrades

Tags: 12.10, upgrade, 13.04

i'm trying to upgrade from 12.10 to 13.04 and for about an hour it's been trying to download files and it stops at 1444/1447 and says (Could not download upgrades)

any help ?

Comment: Try going to System Settings --> Software & Updates and switch servers.

Comment: i did and it didn't work , because it's downloading every thing in high speed but when it reaches 1444 it say (Could not download upgrades Forbidden )